# Binomial series proof question for when k is negative. Why is it called a binomial series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am reading this text:

[image]

I am confused as to how we get from:

$$\frac{|k-n|}{n+1}|x|$$

to

$$\frac{|1-\frac{k}{n}|}{1+ \frac{1}{n}}|x|$$

$k$ is negative right so doesn't the numerator become $|-k - n|$? But I guess this is the same thing as $|k + n|$ inside absolute value signs? Is that right?

On a high level that I'll understand (I'm taking calc 2), why is it called the binomial series?

Comment: "*I'm confused as to how we get from...*"  You forgot absolute values around the $|x|$ in this line.  As for making the transition from the one form to the other, just multiply the fraction by $1$ which in this case will be written as $\frac{1/n}{1/n}$.  Next, remember that $a|b+c| = |ab+ac|$ and that $|a-b|=|b-a|$.

Comment: It is called binomial series because its coefficients are the binomial coefficients $\dbinom{k}{n} $.

Comment: @darijgrinberg why is that important?

Comment: Because you can use this series expansion to prove lots of properties of binomial coefficients (the "generating functions" method).